# Read XML element that contains arrays from web service response

Tags: c#, xml, webservice-client

I'm currently making a web service client (a C# web application) that consumes data from my vendor's web service. Since I'm not a programmer & this is my 1st time dealing with web service, I learned from many tutorials on consuming simple web service data. However I got stuck I getting the value contained within an array.

This is the web service response in XML format which I can get from SOAP client such as SoapUI:

```
    <GetSiteDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <SiteDataResult 
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KPIService"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:SiteName>PMU88</a:SiteName>
            <a:SiteLocation>EcoHill</a:SiteLocation>
            <a:SiteData>
                <a:DateIntervalNode>
                    <a:Date>2019-01-01</a:Date>
                    <a:Temperature>
                        <a:TemperatureNode>
                            <a:AverageTemperature>35</a:AverageTemperature>
                            <a:Unit>C</a:Unit>
                        </a:TemperatureNode>
                    </a:Temperature>
                </a:DateIntervalNode>
                <a:DateIntervalNode>
                    <a:Date>2019-01-02</a:Date>
                    <a:Temperature>
                        <a:TemperatureNode>
                            <a:AverageTemperature>32</a:AverageTemperature>
                            <a:Unit>C</a:Unit>
                        </a:TemperatureNode>
                    </a:Temperature>
                </a:DateIntervalNode>
            </a:SiteData>
        </SiteDataResult>
    </GetSiteDataResponse>
```

To consume the web service data in web application, I add a service reference in the web application that links to the web service WSDL. Result parameters will be displayed as labels in the web page. This is my code behind:

```
public partial class SiteTemp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnInvoke_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.siteTemperatureData myWebService = new ServiceReference1.siteTemperatureDataClient();

        string username = "user1";
        string password = "mypassword";
        string siteID = "1104";

        lblSiteName.Text = myWebService.GetSiteData(username, password, siteID).SiteName;
        lblSiteLocation.Text = myWebService.GetSiteData(username, password, siteID).SiteLocation;
        lblDate1.Text = ???
        lblTemperature1.Text = ???
        lblUnit1.Text = ???
        lblDate2.Text = ???
        lblTemperature2.Text = ???
        lblUnit2.Text = ???
    }
}
```

I can get the value of SiteName & SiteLocation but I have no idea how get the value of Date, AverageTemperature & Unit because the element type of 'SiteData' is an array and I have to go further down the hierarchy to get the data that I need. In most related threads I can see how people obtain the value from an array buy in my case there's also array within an array. Any help /clue/hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't post the entire xml.  You are missing the namespace 'a' which is needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I missed it when I was copying & pasting but the post has been edited to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement siteDataResult = doc.Descendants(ns + "SiteDataResult").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace aNs = siteDataResult.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("a");

            Site site = new Site();
            site.siteName = (string)siteDataResult.Element(aNs + "SiteName");
            site.siteLocation  = (string)siteDataResult.Element(aNs + "SiteLocation");

            site.dict = siteDataResult.Descendants(aNs + "DateIntervalNode")
                .GroupBy(x => (DateTime)x.Element(aNs + "Date"), y => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
                    (int)y.Descendants(aNs + "AverageTemperature").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)y.Descendants(aNs + "Unit").FirstOrDefault()
                    )
                )
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class Site
    {
        public string siteName { get; set; }
        public string siteLocation { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<DateTime, KeyValuePair<int, string>> dict { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but may I know what is supposed to be my xml FILENAME if the xml is a response from a web service?

Comment: That is why I read file into a string.  Your response from the web service is a string so you do not need to read from file.  Just use the Parse method to convert string to a XDocument.